# jQuery filter function selector error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function like this :

```
$.fn.filterByClass = function(cls) {
    var o = $(this);
    return o.filter(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("class") == cls) {
        return $(this);
      }
    });
  };
```

If I have multiple forms and I create a selector like this :

```
$form = $('form');
```

Then later on in my code I need to filter them :

```
$form_one = $form.filterByClass('mykls');
```

And I get the correct element, everything works as I wanted. However when I want to search within this 'filtered' form like :

```
$form_one.find('div')
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
---------------
message: "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

However if I directly select by class name rather than filtering it like this :

```
$form_one = $('form.mykls');
```

Then :

```
$form_one.find('div')
```

Works without any problems. Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

I should use some kind of grepping/filtering to get the right form and I cannot directly look with a given class, but I omitted that part because it's irrelevant.

**Edit :**

Here is the wrapper of the code :

```
var myApp = myApp || {};

myApp.filters = (function($){
  $.fn.filterByClass = function(cls) {
    var o = $(this);
    return o.filter(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("class") == cls) {
        return $(this);
      }
    });
  };

  var $wrapper = $('#notification_filters'),
      $form = $('form', $wrapper);

  var init = function(options) {
    $currentForm = $form.filterByClass(options.formClass);
    console.log($currentForm.find('div')); 
  };

return {
    init: init
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce the error!](http://jsfiddle.net/ypudpd46/)

Comment: ok I'll add some more context to it in edit

Comment: `return o.filter()` returns a jQuery collection, it **has** `find` method. Problem must be something else.

Comment: Do you have other libraries loaded, like `prototypejs`?

Comment: @cookiemonster please see my edit, I got jquery

Comment: @undefined does my edit help?

Comment: I can't get any such error. You need to produce an example that fully represents the problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle? What's wrong with `$collection.filter('.className')` after all?

Comment: ...side note, `var o = $(this)` is unnecessary. Just do `return this.filter(function() {...`. Also, inside the filter, there's no reason to return a jQuery object, and so there's no reason for the `if` at all.. It will be much faster if you do `return this.className === cls;`.

Comment: @undefined d'oh do I feel embarrassed, I'm pretty sure I've tried that `$collection.filter('.className')` and wasn't working for some reason, I might have omitted the dot, but that worked. Can you please make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @undefined: That's a little different, though it may be what he wants. Seems right now that he wants a full match of the element's class, but perhaps that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filterByClass` method returns a jQuery object which should have the `find` method. I couldn't reproduce the error.

If you want to filter  the elements that have a specific className you can use the `filter` method:

```
$collection.filter('.className');
```

Also note that you don't have to create a jQuery object in your method as `this` is already a jQuery collection and you should return a boolean value in the `filter` callback, a truthy value keeps the element and a falsy value removes the element from the collection.

```
$.fn.filterByClass = function(cls) {
    // `this` refers to a jQuery collection
    return this.filter(function() {
        // `this` here refers to the current raw Element object
        return this.className === cls;
    });
};
```

Note that above method returns the elements that only have `cls` className. For filtering the elements that one of their classNames is `cls` you can use the `String.prototype.indexOf` method or the jQuery `hasClass` method.

```
return this.className.indexOf(cls) > -1;
```

Or for avoiding incorrect matching:

```
return $.inArray(this.className.split(/\s/g), cls) > -1;
```